# Meaning of "the question follows from"

Tags: meaning

When one says "The question follows from A.", does that mean that A answers the question, or that A is a justification to consider the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The question follows from A" means that the question results from A.

The verb "follow", similar to "arise" in this case, is used to indicate logical consequence. We can say, for example:

- It follows from A that B is correct.